# should I regularly change the Firebase API key when it expired ? what makes the API key recreated in Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

so in my iOS app, I had to face this issue:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
        "errors": [{
            "message": "API key expired. Please renew the API key.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "badRequest"
        }],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

it is said my API key is expired, fortunately I can solve the problem by following the solution in here: [Firebase authentication - expired api key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948073/firebase-authentication-expired-api-key)

I have to replace the API key in my iOS app using the most recent API key from Google API console

[image]

it little bit weird that creation date for my iOS and Android app is the same at 26 February 2019. do I make something wrong that triggers the API key to be recreated at 26 February 2019 ?  what makes the API key recreated in Firebase?

I am new in using Firebase, I just imagine, if my apps already used by so many people, and suddenly I have to change manually the API key then it means a lot of users can't use the app and I have to republish the app on Google Play and Play Store.

now I am still in development, the first time I create the iOS project was on March 2018 and the API key creation date was 26 February 2019, I am pretty sure that 26 February 2019 is the date when I create the Android app on my firebase in the same project of my iOS app. is that makes the API key recreated ?

I am worried, need some information here. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand *what* API is expired here, but the keys that you're supposed to put in your app should not auto-expire (precisely for the reasons you mention). They also not like traditional API keys, but more like configuration data that your app uses to find its project on the servers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public